# Installing openjdk7-jre on debian squeeze server

Tags: java, apt-get

I am trying to update a server to use openjdk-7-jre using

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

This returns this.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-7-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

apt-get is reading from a file called /etc/apt/sources.list

In this file I have.

```
 # Generated by ndn-autoupdate
 deb http://hg.openjdk.java.net/build-infra/jdk7/jre/ squeeze main
 deb-src http://hg.openjdk.java.net/build-infra/jdk7/jre/ squeeze main
 deb http://debian.di.newdream.net/ squeeze ndn
 deb http://debian.newdream.net/ squeeze main contrib non-free
 deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
 deb http://debian.newdream.net/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
 deb http://www.backports.org/debian/ squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
```

This does not work nor does just adding deb http://hg.openjdk.java.net/ instead. So I guess at this point what I need is the correct url to use in order to download openjdk-7-jre what do I need to add to the sources.list file to download the repo. I have tried several different suggestions found online and they don't work.

Comment: What are those other repositories? I only recognize http://security.debian.org and http://www.backports.org.

Comment: Is your question specific to squeeze? Can you server be upgraded to wheezy? Wheezy, jessie and sid have openjdk in their main and security repositories: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/openjdk-7-jre

Answer (score -1):

try source list generator and change your sourceslist, but in any case copy that information u have in another file in order not to get lost 
this site for example http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: That source generator does not offer a source line for a java.net repository.